# Is "My would be wife" correct?

Tags: word-order

When I'm saying the sentence

> She is my would be wife

Can I say "she is would be my wife"?

Would be my wife

Comment: What meaning do you want to communicate? For example, are you talking about somebody that you would like to have as your wife, or somebody that wants to be your wife?

Comment: Taking about somebody

Comment: My *wife-to-be* sounds much better, as does *my fiancée*.

Comment: @Wyatt it sounds better... but only if that's what is meant... "would-be wife" can mean something very different.

Comment: Possibly related: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/19511/is-the-term-would-be-just-an-indian-usage-or-universal

Answer (score 4):

The first is fine, though a bit odd...

We'd probably phrase it as

> She is my would-be wife.

This would mean that she wants to be your wife but isn't... and you may or may not share that aspiration with her. "[Would-be](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/would-be)" is a special word/concept.

> Desiring, attempting, or professing to be:
>
> - "*Would-be home buyers will have a somewhat easier time getting loans*" (Wall Street Journal).

It can also be used in a derogatory way, implying that their attempt to gain that position or status is futile.

> 3. *derogatory* a person who wants or professes to be something that he is not

As a note, this seems to have a special meaning in Indian English that may not be as recognized in other dialects:

> 4. *Indian* the person to whom one is engaged to be married; fiancé or fiancée

The second is wrong. Both "is" and "would be" are verbs and they don't work together that way, particularly since "is" is present tense and "would be" is a conditional.

Even in the Indian sense of this phase, the determiner "my" needs to proceed the adjective "would-be", so this word order is incorrect.

Another example:

> 1. This is my black dog.
> 2. **This is black my dog. (incorrect)

The first example is correct. "Black" is describing dog and "my" shows ownership of the black dog.

The second example is wrong. The only possible way this could be correct is if "Black" is the name of your dog but then you need a comma:

> This is Black, my dog.

---

You **can**, however, say:

> She would be my wife.

This is fine because you haven't doubled up your verbs. It's not a very modern construction, though. It sounds like it's about 100 years out of date... but sometimes (in special situations) we do say

> If you would be my wife, I'd be the happiest man in the world.

Comment: Related to would-be, the [the -to-be suffix (wife-to-be)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/to-be)